# Web API 2 get up and running on local IIS

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api2

I have Web API 2 C# project which runs fine through visual studio. I type URL to test like this:

```
http://localhost:51754/api/email/1
```

It shows me XML file. However when I publish and set up IIS I get

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden.
```

I am new to this and my question is what kind of configuration I need to have it run on IIS. I am using .NET Framework Version 4.0 Integrated Application Pool to run it.

Answer (score 1):

Probably ASP.NET is not registered within your IIS. Try running the following command from a DOS prompt with elevated user account:

```
C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir
```

Obviously you might need to adapt the path to `aspnet_regiis.exe` depending on your specific OS and version of the framework. Once you have registered ASP.NET 4.0 with IIS make sure that you restart it for changes to take effect:

```
iisreset
```

Comment: I did that still the same. My IIS is running fine I have other projects in there that are all running and they work okay. Maybe this helps I started WepAPI project as a blank one so it runs from Visual Studio but when I Publish there is nothing there except bin Models and package.config PrecompiledApp.config and Web.config

Comment: Make sure that your IIS is configured properly. You must have a website pointing to the physical location of your web application with a `web.config` file at the root and a `bin` folder containing the compiled assemblies.